# progress bar is not working in Next JS 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next JS 13 app dir and I wanted to implement progress bar to it. for this I used `nextjs-progressbar` package and used it in the root `layout` file. but it is not working. is there a way to implement progress bar in app dir?

```
"use client";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import NextNProgress from "nextjs-progressbar";
import { wrapper } from "../store";

function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body className="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <ChakraProvider>
          <NextNProgress color="#06373a" />
          {children}
        </ChakraProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(RootLayout);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use this npm package: [next-nprogress-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-nprogress-bar) which can be used for both app directory and directory pages.

Comment: Awesome package!
Thank you Skyleen_ for creating this package. 

Comment: This looks like a great package, with the only set back that your entire application/website will be client side as far as i understand from the docs: "Once "use client" is defined in a file, all other modules imported into it, including child components, are considered part of the client bundle."
ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#client-components

Comment: this package does not work with router.push

Answer (score 2):

a temp solution, needs some improvements though...

```
'use client'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import NProgress from 'nprogress'
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

type InternalLinkProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode
    href: URL | string | { query: { [key: string]: number | string | boolean } }
    as?: string
    className?: string
    passHref?: boolean
    progress?: boolean
    onClick?: () => void
}

export default function CustomLink(props: InternalLinkProps) {
    const pathname = usePathname()
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()
    const { progress = true, onClick, ...rest } = props

    useEffect(() => {
        NProgress.configure({
            showSpinner: false,
            trickleSpeed: 100,
        })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!progress) return

        NProgress.done()

        return () => {
            NProgress.done()
        }
    }, [pathname, props.href, progress, searchParams])

    return (
        <>
            <Link
                {...rest}
                onClick={() => {
                    onClick?.()
                    if (!progress) return
                    if (props.href === pathname) return
                    NProgress.start()
                }}>
                {props.children}
            </Link>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use loading.tsx file under app/ directory and wrap all of the components in layout.tsx into a `<Suspense/>` from react like

```
<Suspense fallback={<Loading/>}>
...your components...
</Suspense>
```

that's how you can achieve something like ngprogress in nextjs 13 app directory.

Reference: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/loading-ui

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE FOR NEXTJS 13 APP ROUTER

in my nextJs project, I used **[NextTopLoader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-toploader)** as below:

1. `yarn add nextjs-toploader`
2. Usage with `app/layout.js` for app folder structure

For rendering add `<NextTopLoader />` to your `return()` inside the `<body></body>` of `RootLayout()`:

```
import NextTopLoader from 'nextjs-toploader';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <NextTopLoader />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is invalid for Next version 13 because next 13 uses 'next/navigation' instead of 'next/router'. There is no router.events in next/navigation. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#migrating-from-nextrouter

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. In Nextjs 13 (App Router), I used another library that I wrote above how to use @ChrisGrimmett

Answer (score 1):

I don't like any `useEffect` hacks, as they increase the code complexity and more.

I use `nextjs-toploader` with no problems.
Inside `app/layout.jsx` file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import NextTopLoader from 'nextjs-toploader';

export default function Layout({ children, user }) {
   ...
return (
<html id="pageRoot">
  <body className="...">
    <NextTopLoader />
    ...
  </body>
</html>
)}
```

Comment: next-toploader uses client component itself fyi

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck there and then realized that Next.JS 13 is pretty new and a lot different from Next.js 12 from the development side.

I think we should wait until the developer of that package resolves the compatibility issues.

Comment: is there a manual way?

Comment: You can develop a custom progress bar on your own. Here is a resource link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dgnr3akrMHg

Comment: what he did is set a loader to take the whole screen, and just display a loader until the route changes. when building a progress bar we need numbers to set to progress percent. meaning progress bar works by passing a dynamic percent to it. how can I get the percent of the progress?

Comment: The native way is you can set the minimum length of the progress bar to 25 to 30 percent & increase it by 10% every second until the route changes. When the route changes, you can set it to 100$ and then hide it. Ths is the native way to do it.

Comment: how can I get how many seconds it takes to load the route? some pages load faster and some load slow based on connection, component renders, or even pre renders.. so how can I manage this? if you can provide me a code.

Comment: Try this. It'll tell you when to start loading and when to end it. In the middle, try to add the loading by 10%.

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide/version-11#update-usage-of-routerevents

Make sure to import the router and use 'use client'

Comment: I think routing in Next 13 is changed.

Comment: can you post the code to implement in `layout.js`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I found in Next.JS 12 or earlier versions, we could use "router.event" to know when a page is changing and when it changed. Unfortunately, this feature is currently not supported in Next.JS 13. Hopefully, it'll be available soon. 

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-router#userouter:~:text=router.events%20is%20not%20currently%20supported

Comment: I just find out there is another library that works great in NextJS 13 App directory. It's called nextjs-toploader.

Comment: Yes, I'm using that library in 2024 nextjs 14 and it works just awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nprogress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nprogress) package directly. See instructions on their page on how to install. I had also to install `@types/nprogress` for TS type declarations.

In _app.tsx:

```
import { Router } from 'next/router';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';
Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', NProgress.start);
Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', NProgress.done);
Router.events.on('routeChangeError', NProgress.done);
```

Make sure to include the css that comes with the package. In my case we use the SCSS preprocessor, so in one of the global .scss files I've added:

```
@import 'node_modules/nprogress/nprogress.css';
```

Comment: The OP is talking about Next.js 13's new `app` directory. The solution you showed here is only compatible with the `pages` directory.

Answer (score 0):

To create router.event, you need to create the following two files

```
useEffect(() => {
        // You can now use the current URL
        NProgress.start()
    }, [pathname ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        NProgress.done()
        // You can now use the current URL
    }, [ searchParams]);
```

And we use this package in rendering

```
<NextNProgress color="#29D" startPosition={0.3} stopDelayMs={200} height={3} showOnShallow={true} />
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you work with NextJs App router (version 13, 14) You must do as follows:

in the NextJS app router version, the `layout.tsx` files persist across routes and maintain state, so for the progress bar you must create a file called `template.tsx` (or `template.js`) next to `layout.tsx.`
(**Note**: templates create a new instance for each of their children on navigation)

```
'use client'
import { AppProgressBar as ProgressBar } from 'next-nprogress-bar'
const Template = ({ children }: any) => {

   return (
      <>
         <ProgressBar
            height="4px"
            color="#292929"
            options={{ showSpinner: true }}
            shallowRouting
         />
         {children}
      </>
   )
}

export default Template
```

Answer (score -1):

Just create a custom `<Link>{text}</Link>` wrapper or routing function and attach an onclick listener to it ie `<Link onClick={NProgress.start)....`

then in RootLayout, wrap the "children" ie. `<Wrapper>{children}</Wrapper>` Node with a client component

```js
"use client";
export const Wrapper = ({children})=> { 
    const pathname = usePathname();
    useEffect(()=> NProgress.done(),[pathname])
    return children
}
```